# How to redirect on login to a specific page if a specific meta user is empty

Tags: redirect, login, user-meta, meta-value

I would like to indicate that if you do not have the first_name filled in when logging in, you will be redirected to a specific page, for example /onboarding and if the first_name field is filled, you would be redirected to the home page. I would like it to always perform the check and redirect whenever first_name is empty

I am trying the following code but it does not work.

```
function login_redirect( $redirect, $user ) {    
// Get user meta
$field_empty = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'first_name', true );

// Empty
if ( empty( $field_empty ) ) {
    $redirect = '/onboarding';
} else {
 
    $redirect = '/';     
}

return $redirect;
}
```

Comment: are you binding this function with some hook? if so can you share that part of the code?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Comment: This is the complete code.

`function onboarding_redireccion( $redirect, $user )  {    
    // Get user meta
    $value = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'first_name', true );

    // Empty
    if ( empty( $value ) ) {
        $redirect = '/onboarding';
    } else {
        // Get the "home_url" url
        $redirect = '/';     
    }
    
    return $redirect;
}

add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'onboarding_redireccion', 10, 3 );`

The problem with this is that, even though I have first_name with content, the code keeps redirecting me to /onboarding